# Built in types of marker icons in react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I wanted to know if there is any other type of marker that comes with react leaflet apart from the default blue one. Also without uploading any icon image, how can I customize the existing marker icon? I have already tried to refer many online sources but everywhere it consists of uploading your own marker icon which I would not like to do in my project. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the [CircleMarker](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker) and... that is it.

The Circle Marker offers some style customization though.

Then you have plenty [plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers), not sure how to use them with React Leaflet. But it might be not too difficult given that you just need to specify an `icon` prop on the Marker.

Comment: Thank you this was quite useful!